# CakePHPで【FromHelper cloud not be found】というエラーが発生する

Tags: php, cakephp, dotinstall

[image: エラー表示画像]

ただいまCakePHPをドットインストールで勉強中ものです。
動画通りに進めていますが、タイトルのエラーに困ってます。
どなたかエラーの謎を教えてください。

＜ドットインストールの動画＞
http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_cakephp/7515

参考までに「PostController」「add.ctp」「index.ctp」のソースを公開します。

### PostController

```
<?php

class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index(){
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
        //$this->set('title', '記事一覧');
    }

    public function view($id = null){
        $this->Post->id = $id;
        $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());

    }

    public function add(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')){
            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash('Success!');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('failed!');
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

### add.ctp

```
<h2>Add post</h2>

<?php
echo $this->From->create('Post');
echo $this->From->input('title');
echo $this->From->input('body',array('rows'=>3));
echo $this->From->end('Save Post');


?>
```

### index.ctp

```
<h2>記事一覧</h2>

<ul>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
<li>
<?php
//echo h($post['Post']['title']);
echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],'/posts/view/'.$post['Post']['id']);
?>

</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<h2>Add Post</h2>
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Add post', array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'add'));?>
```

Comment: エラーメッセージは画像だけではなくテキストのものも記載していただけると回答しやすいです。

Answer (score 2):

エラーページの「Stack Trace」には発生個所でどの関数を実行していたかの情報が記載されています。APPフォルダ内では「add.ctp line 4」がトップですが、

> <h2>Add post</h2>
>
> <?php
>   echo $this->From->create('Post');

この4行目の`$this->From`が`$this->Form`の誤りだというエラーですね。

Comment: すみません。解決しました・・・。スペルミスには気をつけます

Comment: @DaikiYamada 本回答で解決した場合には回答の承認（チェックマークをクリックする）をお願いします。